# Running a single BehaviorSpace experiment on NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I need to perform a single run of a BehaviorSpace experiment so that I can run the NetLogo model headless on Google cloud/AWS.

I tried writing a simple test code that just prints an output following the 'setup' command. However this prints the output twice. Am I doing something wrong? I tried entering 0 runs in parallel but this threw an IllegalArgumentException.

Here is the setup of the experiment:

Repetitions: 1
Setup commands: setup
Go commands: setup
Time limit: 1
Simultaneous runs in parallel: 1

Comment: It looks like you are running setup twice, once as the Setup command, then then again as the Go command.  Is that what you intend?  Is there no procedure to call after setup?

Comment: Ah thanks so much! That did not occur to me. I was running the same procedure to both setup as display the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by Charles in the comment section:

I was running setup twice! Doh.